# C Setting pointer to a char* to a char*

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a function

```
setCharVal(char *s, int value){
   valueStruct* makeStruct = malloc(sizeof(valueStruct));
   makeStruct->s = s;
   //set other values
}
```

valueStruct has a char*s; when I print the s going into the function, it's fine, but when i print makeStruct->s, it prints nothing.

I've tried

```
makeStruct->s = strdup(s);
```

and

```
makeStruct->s = malloc(sizeof(s);
makeStruct->s = s;
```

and neither of those work; it still prints nothing for makeStruct->s.

I'm calling setCharVal with

```
setCharVal(anotherStruct.s);
```

Comment: Show where `s` comes from and where you try to print `makeStruct->s`.  The problem is probably not the assignment statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
makeStruct->s = malloc(sizeof(s);
makeStruct->s = s;
```

causes a memory leaks, and gains nothing.

What you should do it to copy the string to the allocated buffer (also, the length is given using `strlen` if `s` is a string or from outside the function, not `sizeof`):

```
// added valueStruct* because I assume you want to return it from the function
valueStruct* setCharVal(char *s,size_t s_size int value){
   valueStruct* makeStruct = malloc(sizeof(valueStruct));
   makeStruct->s = malloc(s_size);
   memcpy(makeStruct->s, s, s_size);
   // ..
   return makeStruct;
}
```